# I am new in google Dialogflow, I am trying to map training phrases with enity

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to create intent and able to create intent and entity but when I map entity with training phrases hall phrase mapped with that Entity. So I just want Phrases content map with particular entity which is specified.

```
{
    text: I want to eat Apple and Banana,
    entityType: '@' + Fruits,
    alias: Fruits,
    userDefined: false
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are facing this issue  because of not defining the texts in the [parts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#part) parameter  of training Phrases. In the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#trainingphrase), they have mentioned it that dialogflow API does not automatically annotate training phrases like the Dialogflow console does. You need to make an ordered list of the sentences and give white spaces at the part boundaries, so that training phrases are well formatted when parts are concatenated. Also we have to set the “UserDefined” parameter to “True”.

You can make the following changes to your Json file.

```
{
  "trainingPhrases": [
    {
      "type": "EXAMPLE",
      "parts": [
        {
          "text": "i want to eat  "
        },
        { "text":"apple",
          "entityType":"@fruits",
            "alias": "fruit",
            "userDefined": "True"
        },

        {
            "text":" and "
        },
        {

            "text":"orange ",
            "entityType":"@fruits",
            "alias":"fruit",
            "userDefined":"True"

        }
        

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```